# Custom Registrations Controller for Devise not Overriding Create Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have been fighting with this for days now. I have created my own Registrations Controller to allow for an amdin to create and delete users. I have left the `:registerable` module in my devise configuration, as I also want to users to be able to edit their profiles. I have tried taking that module out just to see if it would solve my issue. The problem that I have, is that when I create a new user as an admin, it still signs that user in, despite having my own create action. I have tried everything that I can think of to get beyond this and I am stuck.

My Registrations Controller:

```
  class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  load_and_authorize_resource

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    resource.build
    if resource.save
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      clean_up_passwords(resource)
      render_with_scope :new
    end
  end

end
```

Application Controller: => note, `after_sign_up_path_for` was overriden here as a test to see if that would work

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    flash[:error] = exception.message
    redirect_to projects_url
  end

  protected

    def stored_location_for(resource)
      nil
    end

    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      projects_url
    end

    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      users_path
    end

end
```

Routes File:

```
DeviseTest::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controller => { :registrations => "registrations"}
  devise_scope :user do
    get '/login' => 'devise/sessions#new'
    get '/logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end

  resources :users, :controller => "users"

  resources :projects

  root :to => 'home#index'

  end
```

And my Users Controller for admin view

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  load_and_authorize_resource

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.xml
  def index
    @users = User.excludes( :id => current_user.id )

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @users }
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.xml
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(users_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

Rake Routes Output:

```
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        {:action=>"cancel", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                   login GET    /login(.:format)               {:controller=>"devise/sessions", :action=>"new"}
                  logout GET    /logout(.:format)              {:controller=>"devise/sessions", :action=>"destroy"}
                   users GET    /users(.:format)               {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
                         POST   /users(.:format)               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)           {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
                projects GET    /projects(.:format)            {:action=>"index", :controller=>"projects"}
                         POST   /projects(.:format)            {:action=>"create", :controller=>"projects"}
             new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"projects"}
            edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"projects"}
                 project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"show", :controller=>"projects"}
                         PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"update", :controller=>"projects"}
                         DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"projects"}
                    root        /(.:format)                    {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}
```

Everything else works as expected, I just cannot get the created user to not be signed in. It's not a huge issue for creating one user, but if I need to create 3 or 4, it's a huge p.i.t.a to have to signout, signin, every single time.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does `rake routes` output?

Comment: Added the rake routes output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the third line of your routes.rb file, I think you mean `:controllers => …`, not `:controller => …`. You're missing an 's'.

Comment: I must have overlooked that a hundred times. Just proves that sometimes it takes and extra set of eyes. Thank you.